# Fancybox V2 CSS for V3

Tags: fancybox-2, fancybox-3

I am trying to migrate a project with Fancybox V2.5 to V3, but it needs to retain the original look.

How can I get the original X in a circle on the top right corner and other options such as rounded corners, shadow, etc to work in V3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use callback to add additional elements and then use css snippets from v2 to style, for example:

```
$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({
  toolbar  : false,
  smallBtn : false,
  arrows   : false,
  idleTime : false,
  loop     : true,
  transitionEffect : false,
  animationDuration : 333,
  afterLoad : function(instance, slide) {
    $('<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;" data-fancybox-close></a><a title="Previous" class="fancybox-item fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;" data-fancybox-prev><span></span></a><a title="Next" class="fancybox-item fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;" data-fancybox-next><span></span></a>').appendTo( slide.$content );
  }
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/full/ePYNZo

Comment: Thanks. But the rounded corners from the old fancybox-skin are missing? To which element should this be applied for an iframe?

Comment: Since iframe (`.fancybox-iframe`) covers whole parent element (`.fancybox-content`) and both can have background color, you have to set border-radius to both of those elements.